# Can anyone tell me how to fix this error nomodulenaned pyttsx3.drivers.sapi full error here down

Tags: python, pyttsx3

SO here I imported pyttsx3 and wanted my ai to speak but it gave me a error full error here https://drive.google.com/file/d/12fa4KdSQ6JiEYjJHljc3JuLiFW-eYtKD/view?usp=sharing

```
import pyttsx3

Assistant = pyttsx3.init('sapi.5')
voices = Assistant.getProperty('voices')
print(voices)
Assistant.setProperty('voices',voices(1).id)
def Speak(audio):
    print("   ")
    Assistant.say(audio)
    print("   ")
    Assistant.runAndWait()


Speak('Hello sir, I am Y.P.A')
```

Comment: Full error here:-https://drive.google.com/file/d/12fa4KdSQ6JiEYjJHljc3JuLiFW-eYtKD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If there are some errors in my asking question then plz forgive me as I am new                         :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo when initializing your Assistant

```
Assistant = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
```

Comment: Thx for your help but now it gave me one more error!:( 
PS C:\Users\yuvra\Desktop> & C:/Users/yuvra/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/yuvra/Desktop/Pranks/Chatbots/Y.P.A.py
[<pyttsx3.voice.Voice object at 0x000001BFF5E93640>, <pyttsx3.voice.Voice object at 0x000001BFF5E91990>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\yuvra\Desktop\Pranks\Chatbots\Y.P.A.py", line 6, in <module>
    Assistant.setProperty('voices',voices(1).id)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
PS C:\Users\yuvra\Desktop>

Comment: Now it gave me a new error:( `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: also `PS C:\Users\yuvra\Desktop> & C:/Users/yuvra/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/yuvra/Desktop/Pranks/Chatbots/Y.P.A.py
[<pyttsx3.voice.Voice object at 0x000001BBD4C37610>, <pyttsx3.voice.Voice object at 0x000001BBD4C35960>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\yuvra\Desktop\Pranks\Chatbots\Y.P.A.py", line 7, in <module>
    Assistant.setProperty('voices',voices(1).id)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
PS C:\Users\yuvra\Desktop> `

Comment: This one is also a typo for the way you are accessing the list. Instead of `voices(1).id` do `voices[1].id`. Installing a linter for your editor can help you solve most of these.